# Visualizing multi-state lattice from a data set

Tags: visualization, list-manipulation, data, lattices

Is there any way to make Mathematica visualize a multistate square lattice? That is, I have a data set from a simulation that is *x* coloumns wide and *y* rows tall (just a simple .dat file), where each cell has a value *n_i = 0,1,2,3* - and I then want Mathematica to draw a *x* by *y* square lattice and color each square in the lattice corresponding to the state in the data set, e.g. 0 = red, 1 = green, 2 = blue, 3 = yellow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`. Note that Mesh setting is optional. It works well if squares are large, but should not be used for small square sizes. `MatrixPlot` is very intelligent for large arrays of data - it deduces best approximate visual form: "sufficiently large or sparse matrices are downsampled so that their structure is visible in the plot" ~ Documentation.

Make some data and save in .DAT file:

```
dat = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {13, 13}];
Export["test.dat", dat];
```

Now import that file and plot:

```
imp = Import["test.dat"];
MatrixPlot[imp, ColorRules -> {0 -> Red, 1 -> Green, 2 -> Blue, 3 -> Yellow},Mesh -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayPlot[]`/`MatrixPlot[]` are the most straightforward ways to go about this. Alternatively, one could use `Raster[]` or `Image[]` for the purpose:

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> "MersenneTwister"]; (* for reproducibility *)
            arr = RandomInteger[{0, 3}, {15, 20}]];

colorRules = Thread[Range[0, 3] -> List @@@ {Red, Green, Blue, Yellow}];
```

From here, we could do either of

```
Image[arr /. colorRules, ImageSize -> 300]
```

or

```
Graphics[Raster[Reverse[arr] /. colorRules]]
```

to give this:

[image: some colored lattice]

Comment: Thank you - in this particular case, I happen to like that there is a grid included, but I've noted yours too for when I need to make a completely clean/code-color only representation. Which I happen to also need.

Comment: @nielsen to remove the grid in the other solution, just use `Mesh->False` - that's what the second sentence of that answer is all about.